# Writing a Java adder remover, method code template for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-templates

There are too many time I encounter the need to write an adder/remover methods for lists:

```
public void addSomething(Something something){
    somethings.add(something);
}

public void removeSomething(Something something){
    somethings.remove(something);
}
```

If I got it right, then Eclipse templates can support auto complete... for example, if I have a:

```
Vector<Something> somethings=new Vector<Something>();
```

I would like the template to add the method to the Auto-Complete of Eclipse, and would auto complete the **entire** method:

```
public void addSomething(Something something){
    somethings.add(something);
}
```

when I type "**add**" + (**Ctrl** + **Space**)...

Any idea how to accomplish something like this... perhaps point me to a reading material specific to this sort of subject.

** UPDATE **

Well, this is what I have so far:

```
public final void add${type:elemType(collection)}(${type} ${varName:newName(type)}) {
    ${collection}.add(${varName}); 
}
```

Here is the problem though, If I type "add" + (Ctrl + Space):

In the class level, and the collection is declared as a field, I get an empty variable as a collection.

```
public final void addtype(type type) {
    collection.add(type);
}
```

In the method level, and the collection is declared as a field, I get an empty variable as a collection.

```
public final void addtype(type type) {
    collection.add(type);
}
```

In the method level, and the collection reference is a local variable of the method I get the correct syntax, but the add method is inside the other method.

```
public void method(...) {
    public final void addSomething(Something something) {
        this.somethings.add(something);
    }
}
```

Which means I don't get field level reference, how can I obtain it?

** UPDATE 2 **

This also gives the same result:

```
public final void add${type:elemType(collection)}(${type} ${varName:newName(type)}) {
    ${collection:field(java.util.Collection)}.add(${varName}); 
}

public final void remove${type:elemType(collection)}(${type} ${varName:newName(type)}) {
    ${collection:field(java.util.Collection)}.remove(${varName}); 
}
```

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally used the following:

```
public final void add${type:elemType(collection)}(${type} ${varName:newName(type)}) {
    ${collection:field(java.util.Collection)}.add(${varName}); 
}

public final void remove${type:elemType(collection)}(${type} ${varName:newName(type)}) {
    ${collection:field(java.util.Collection)}.remove(${varName}); 
}
```

I create this with in a method, and cut it to the class level... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read about available template variables in [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-template-variables.htm). You should be fashion a template based on the existing templates in Eclipse, see 'Templates view' in Eclipse.

Comment: It was not very clear, although at the end it was quite informative.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use `Source > Generate delegate methods`, so you don't have to write template for every method you want to generate.

Assign a hot key for `Generate delegate methods`, whenever you declare a object

```
List<Integer> integer = new ArrayList<Integer>();| <- your cursor
```

Press the hot key, Eclipse will detect current selected object then come up a list of available methods for you.

Comment: Good one my friend, but not what I want... I want something that would do 100% of the work, not 70%.  :) Thanks, see my update.

Comment: I also want a different name "addSomething(Something s)", not only add(Something s);